# Terraform in VS code

Tags: terraform, visual-studio-code

I installed  VS Code and Terraform addin when I want to run my code I get this:

[image: Visual Studio Code window with "Select Environment" requester shown at the top, with options like "Chrome (preview)", "Docker: Debug in Container", "Node.js", "PowerShell"...]

and I don't see the integrate option like a have to PowerShell sorry to the question just hard to get started

Comment: Which vscode plugin did you use?

Comment: Most of the addins gives you the ability to identify the errors, or autocomplete snippets for Terraform. For execution of your tf code, you need to install Terraform on your machine and use a terminal to run the required commands.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HashiCorp.terraform